# I want to install vpn server on windows/unix for internet access

Tags: vpn, firewall, routing

I want to install vpn server on windows/unix whichever runs best to bypass country restrictions to access web sites.

The main purpose is the divert my all internet traffic through connected vpn.

I tried to find a suitable solution but couldn't go through with them. I tried to set it up on Azure VMs with linux or windows 2012 r2 but to no avail. I have also tried configuring Azure Network but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to go with a paid VPN provider, preferably somewhere in the USA or Canada.   You do not want to try to setup your own VPN server via Azure unless you are fully well aware of what you are doing.   It sounds like you live in a country that restricts it's citizens ability to access the internet.   If you were to setup your own external VPN server, and end up not configuring it correctly and ended up getting caught, I could only imagine the consequences might be extreme.

Comment: Thanks but I think it would be best to configure it myself since that will allow me to learn the process too. I would not doing anything which could result in consequences of extreme nature so that would be no problem if I make any mistake along the way as far as I will be able to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to bypass country restrictions to access websites, you could accomplish this with a simple browser proxy instead of using a vpn server.

A browser extension can be found with a quick search for "Chrome proxy" or "Firefox proxy".

Comment: I tried but that is not reliable enough since the required websites sometimes open and sometimes not without any obvious reason.

Comment: Could this just be due to you using a free proxy? Perhaps a paid one would be more reliable for you. To clarify, are you trying to bypass your countries restrictions, or are you trying to trick a website into thinking you are from another country?

Comment: I have setup a proxy server of my own on azure vm (Linux) in another region so you could say it is paid server. Well, aren't they both the same or even if different, I think doing both would achieve the desired result.